# Create a notification looks like the "Shuttle Player" Application

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating a well customised Music Player for Android phone. The App will support devices from 4.0 so I would like to adapt the "Big Content View" for notifications. After searching around, I see the "Shuttle Player" app has exactly what I want. The features I want to add can be listed as follow:

1. Big view, with controllers and closing button.

**2. Always on top of notification list, i.e even when a new notification comes (like new email), my app's ongoing notification will stay steady on top of them and the new one will come at the second position.**

Actually both Google Music Player, CyannogenMod rom's Apollo player and Shuttle Player have the same notification layout, but I have tested the Apollo app and Shuttle Player and only the Shuttle Player does what I want to do..

I could add a remoteviews for the notification, but for the second feature, I still don't know how to adapt that idea. Anyone has experience in those thing? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setPriority()` on your `Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority%28int%29) to indicate relative priority. Higher-priority items will appear towards the top. However, you have no absolute guarantee of being at the top all of the time, as other high-priority notifications may be added.

Also, please allow this behavior to be configurable by the user. *You* may want your `Notification` to always be on top. The *user* may not. The user's opinion is more important than is yours.

Comment: "The user may not. The user's opinion is more important than is yours." - 1 vote for this. Actually I would like to show the full remoteviews (with controllers, which will be changed if the notification downs to the second position). But i will consider a flexible contentview for my notification.